# How do you put numbers in a sign or text?

Tags: rec-room

I'm trying to create a sign that displays a number that can change over time. I want the number to come from a circuit input but I can't figure out how to include the number in the text such that I can change it dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

To include numbers in the text, use one of these special character sequences to display values input on the corresponding pins.

`{R}` to display the value input on the red pin.

`{G}` to display the value input on the green pin.

`{B}` to display the value input on the blue pin.

For example, if you want to display the amount of gold a player has on a sign, you might wire their player stat to the red pin of the sign and then put the following text.

`You have {R} gold.`

If the player then has 80 gold, the `{R}` will be replaced leaving the sign text to read:

`You have 80 gold.`

This works with Signs, Text Gadgets, and for some pins on the Message chip.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `{C}`, `{M}`, `{Y}` and `{K}` to get inputs from the other pins, but their usefulness is mostly limited by their sideeffects.

Comment: I think it would be better to have this as a comment on the other answer than as an answer on its own.

Comment: I agree. Weirdly enough there is no button on the mobile site to add a new comment. Or maybe it's just one of those weird internet point restrictions. Edit: The button on the Desktop version tells me to get 50 internet points first :/

Comment: Bootstrapping a StackExchange account is unfortunately tedious it seems..